# Jquery: how to send one ajax request and save the JSON string for another calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

in my code i have the following

```
var response = "";
function send_ajax(){
 if(response == ""){
   $.ajax({
     url: url
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: "JSON",
     success: function(data){
        response = data;
     }
   });
 }
}
```

my problem is that send_ajax function is called several times in my script, and sometimes alot of ajax calls is send together and no need for that. so i'm searching for a solution in which if one ajax request is send other calls should wait until that function saves the data in the response var and use it.

how can i do that ?

Comment: Prime example of one of the downsides to the callback/event-driven paradigm: synchronization of async calls.

Comment: sup ra_htial theres no callback in your code i asume you want that and to que callers callbacks if the request is ongoing??? other wise just use a bolean to tell them you already made a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the async flag to false, no other calls are made until the first call is done.

```
$.ajax({
     url: url
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: "JSON",
     async: false,
     success: function(data){
        response = data;
     }
   });
```

Comment: i think that should work, if i set async:false & beforeSend callback to check if i have (response != ""){ xhr.abort(); }

Answer (score 0):

```
if(response == ""){
 response = 'waiting';
```

will do the trick, no ?

Comment: Yes that's nice but now how to hold the execution of that call and wait to get the response then continue its execution ?

Comment: you cant hold execution js is single treaded you need to use callbacks

Comment: you can't "hold it" but if you add this response='waiting' bit, then no other call will be made until response is eventually emptied (by an empty-returned AJAX call). Don't change anything else to the function. That should be working. EDIT : to be more clear : JS is event triggered and no execution can be delayed over another equivalent function call. Just put inside the $.ajax callback the function calls that you want to be made AFTER the response is received

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you want the $.ajax to be async, but only allow one ajax request at any time. You could take a look at $.ajaxStart and $.ajaxStop global event

```
var ajaxLock = false;
$.ajaxStart(function(){ajaxLock = true;});
$.ajaxStop(function(){ajaxLock = false;});
var ajaxRequest = function(url, data) {
     if (!ajaxLock) {
        $.ajax({
             url: url
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: "JSON",
             async: false,
             success: function(data){
                response = data;
             }
           });
     }
 }
```